# First Order PDE Initial Value Conditions

Tags: partial-differential-equations

I have the following first order PDE
$$u_t+3tu_x=u $$
subject to $u(x,t)=1+\cos{x}$ along $x+3t=0$

So I tried to parameterise the characteristic curves by s, to do this I said  $\frac{dt}{ds}= 1$,$\frac{dx}{ds}= 3t$, and$\frac{du}{ds}= u$. Now I am trying to find the initial value conditions, normally we just say 
$$x(s=0,r)=r$$ 
$$t(s=0,r)=0$$
$$u(s=0,r)=f(r)$$ 
However, that is when the initial value condition has the form $u(x,0)=f(x)$. What I thought we might be able to to is say that the initial value condition is  $u(x,t=0)= 1+\cos{x}$, but I don't know if this the right way. Can somebody please help me understand how to deal with this "$u(x,t)=1+\cos{x}$ along $x+3t=0$" condition?

Comment: Possible duplicate of  https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2394267/partial-differential-equation-with-initial-condition-on-a-curve#comment4940363_2394267

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The inital conditions aren't correct as you observed. Data is prescribed along $x = r, t = \frac{-r}{3}.$ Thus, the characteristics and initial conditions should be listed as
\begin{align}
\frac{dx}{ds} = 3t;& \;\; x(r,0) = r\\
\frac{dt}{ds} = 1;& \;\; t(r,0) = \frac{-r}{3}\\
\frac{du}{ds} = u;& \;\; u(r,0) = 1 + \cos{(r)}.
\end{align}

From there, we can solve the system, try to write $r$ and $s$ as functions of $x$ and $t,$ i.e. $r = r(x,t),\; s = s(x,t),$ and then ultimately $u(x,t) = u(r(x,t),s(x,t)).$

Comment: I tried something similar to that originally and got a crazy answer by saying $x(r,0)=-3r$, $t(r,0)=r$, and $u(r,0)=1+\cos(-3r)$. Should this have worked and if not why?